# mysql statement prestashop error "checkedFrom"

Tags: mysql

In prestashop, i want to create a new SQL statement for export rows that i want. Here is my code:

```
  SELECT    nx7k_orders.reference
       , nx7k_orders.date_add
       , nx7k_order_detail.product_name
       , nx7k_order_detail.product_quantity
       , nx7k_customer.firstname
       , nx7k_customer.lastname
  FROM  nx7k_orders
  JOIN  nx7k_order_detail
        ON nx7k_order_detail.id_order = nx7k_orders.id_order
  JOIN  nx7k_customer
        ON nx7k_customer.id_shop = nx7k_order_detail.id_shop
```

But, when I click `Save` button, on top it said, error "checkedFrom"

Comment: @utility what you mean, "post error stack"? I just click Save button and on top it said, error "checkedFrom"

Comment: Fragment revised with code formatting

Comment: The error you quote doesn't seem to have any relation to the code you're showing; how and where are you trying to run this query?

Comment: @Pekka웃 i tried to use this query in prestashop - SQL manager

Comment: Even i also faced the same situation solution is you copy the query in sqlformatter and paste the formatted result

Answer (score 1):

i think only works if you give alias to the tables:

```
SELECT no.reference, 
   no.date_add, 
   nod.product_name, 
   nod.product_quantity, 
   nc.firstname, 
   nc.lastname 
FROM   nx7k_orders no 
   JOIN nx7k_order_detail nod 
     ON nod.id_order = no.id_order 
   JOIN nx7k_customer nc 
     ON nc.id_shop = nod.id_shop
```